# Adding new item in RecyclerView with Header causing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

My RecyclerAdapter is working but when I add a new item to it and then click some button, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.

There are two scenario of populating my list, first is when there is a new inserted data thus making its position at the top, the other one is for pagination when the user scrolls down another new 4 previous items will be loaded.

This is for adding new item

```
 //This will be called only if user added some new post
                                      postList.add(0, post);
                                      //Notify the adapter that new item is added
                                      postRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
                                      //Notify the adapter to update all position
                                      postRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, postList.size() + 1 );
```

While in pagination I just normally add old data

```
 postList.add(annonPost);
                            //Update the Recycler adapter that new data is added
                            postRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemInserted(postList.size());
```

This is what my onBindViewHolder looks like.

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    if (viewHolder instanceof ItemViewHolder){

        ItemViewHolder holder = (ItemViewHolder) viewHolder;

//I have a Firebase listeners here that updates the setAttributes automatically when a button is clicked
holder.setAttribute(someValueFromListener, 
postList.get(getItem(holder.getAdapterPosition())).name);
}}}
```

Now since I have a header this is how I get the position and item count

```
 private int getItem(int position){
    return position - 1;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.postList.size() + 1;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position == 0)
        return TYPE_HEADER;

    return TYPE_ITEM;
}
```

Adding new item is okay but once I started to click some button to trigger the Firebase listener I am getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-2`. Is there something wrong with the position? I also checked the value of **getItem(holder.getAdapterPosition())** and it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

that's because of this method:

```
private int getItem(int position){
    return position - 1;
}
```

you should replace it with:

```
private int getItem(int position){
        return this.postList.get(position);
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the big difference between the two?

Comment: currently you are not returning the value of the list you are sowing, you are just returning an index pointing to the previous position of the item.

Comment: In your answer you are returning a list not the index?

Comment: i can help you better if you edit your question and put your adapter class and viewHolder class here.

Comment: Please check this new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240499/recyclerview-with-header-is-throwing-arrayindexoutofboundsexception